# Ng-repeat and directive expand one list item at a time

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, directive

I have an `ng-repeat` code with expandable list items. I would like to expand one item at a time.

The way I am trying to do it is 
in the html file

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parts in data track by $index">
    <li id="titleHelp" ng-click='setItem($index);">
```

and in the directive in the setItem function I want to collapse the previously expanded item and expand the new one. Is it possible to access one repeat element in the directive using index?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you currently expand the list item?
What I would do is set a variable as soon as an item is clicked and in your repeated list do a

```
<div data-ng-repeat="parts in data track by $index">
    <li id="titleHelp" ng-click='setItem($index);">
    <div ng-show="$index = selected_item"> <!-- contents --></div>
```

In your setItem function:

```
$scope.setItem = function(i) {
    $scope.selected_item = i;
}
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your response; in the HTML, you should have `ng-show="$index == selected_item"`

Answer (score 1):

Declare a object

```
$scope.obj={selected:null};
```

After that add a method in the ng repeat,

```
 $scope.isHide = function (id) {

                            if (id == $scope.obj.selected)
                                return $scope.obj.selected = "all";

                            return $scope.obj.selected = id;
                        }
```

If you want to hide div, call this method with the id. Do the same thing for the li if you need.